# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de una celda en Excel que contiene una formula con Openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, formulas, openpyxl, celdas

[image: Los campos que intento leer son estos]alguien que me pueda ayudar. necesito obtener los datos de unas celdas en Excel que fueron calculadas mediante una formula, el problema es que cuando intento capturar el valor de esa celda con un sheet['CW2'].value, me arroja =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B{i+1},BJ{i+1},11)-1 y no el valor calculado.
Si alguien sabe cómo puedo obtener el valor y no la formula le agradezco, estoy usando OpenPyXl. Gracias.

Comment: Si intento meter tu formula en el excel, me da un error diciendo que podría no tratarse de una formula. Estás seguro de que la formula está bien escrita?

Comment: Disculpa amigo tal vez se deba a que la puse con los {} ahí en lugar de i +1 estaría el nombre de la celda 1 y la celda 2, es decir la formula quedaría así por ejemplo =NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B1,BJ1,11)-1, 
Adicional no te funcionará en excel ya que esta fórmula pasada a excel sería =DIAS.LAB.INTL()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener los datos y no las fórmulas de la celda hay que abrir el archivo agregando el parámetro **data_only=True**:

```
workbook = load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, realicé esto, pero al imprimir el valor de la celda que antes me arrojaba la fórmula ahora me arroja None, qué puede ser?

Comment: No he podido reproducir un caso que genere None; de modo que no sé dónde se poduce ese valor

Comment: A mi la solución de Leonardo me funciona perfectamente. Podrías colocar una muestra (no es necesario que sean datos reales) de la hoja que tiene la formula a la que intentas acceder por favor?

Comment: Acabo de añadir una captura muchas gracias.

Comment: Leonardo, acabo de realizar un excel y he realizado estas operaciones propiamente desde excel,  al darle data_only = True, me lee los valores tal y como lo dices, pero lo que pasa es que estos cálculos en el caso real no los obtengo de excel si no que los genero mediante Openpyxl, la idea es hacer los cálculos mediante una función y luego obtener los resultados para hacer diferentes cosas, en este orden de idea me toca crear a mí mismo la lógica de esta función (NETWORKDAYS.INTL)? ya que pensaba generar el cálculo cargar en el excel y luego leer esos datos cálculados...

Comment: Revisando la documentación de openpyxl entiendo que se recupera el valor de una fórmula si se usa excel. De otra forma, si se usa openpyxl para guardar y abrir la hoja de cálculo se retorna la fórmula o None. `:param data_only: controls whether cells with formulae have either the formula (default) or the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet`